# UILabel sizeToFit doesn't stretch to width

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, sizetofit

I am programmatically creating a `UILabel` like this:

```
    hashtagLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, nameLbl.frame.maxY + 5,
    bounds.width-40, layerView.frame.width/3.66))
    hashtagLbl.text = "#Placeholder"
    hashtagLbl.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
    hashtagLbl.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x9B9B9B)
    hashtagLbl.sizeToFit()
    hashtagLbl.numberOfLines = 0
    hashtagLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Now I am loading data and setting the data to the label and I am recalling the `sizeToFit`:

```
        if let text = memberHashtags{
        hashtagLbl.text = text
        hashtagLbl.sizeToFit()

    }
```

Rather than displaying like this (UILabel created in IB):
[image]

the label is displaying like this:

[image]

Comment: did you try to call `hashtagLbl.sizeToFit()` as last statement in your code?

Comment: btw, try to give the label background color so that you can see what's the label's actual width

Comment: @ddb You are right. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @JVS, I made it an answer, so you can vote it and accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to call

```
hashtagLbl.sizeToFit()
```

as last statement in your code